# GPS doesn't work for short distances

Tags: java, android, gps, locationlistener

I'm using an application that uses the gps feature (using AVD on Eclipse). This application works fine when i put the coordinates with the DDMS, but if I insert a point that is very close to the previous point (20-30m), the `onLocationChanged(Location loc)` event is not called (but the application doesn't crash. If I insert a new point that is not so close, the even is correctly called). Is this an emulator's problem? Or is it a problem caused by the `requestLocationUpdates(...)` method? My code is this:

```
public class myActivity extends Activity 
{

    private TextView mytext;
    private LocationManager locmgr = null;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        GPSListener gpsListener=newGPSListener();
        mytext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mytext);

        //grab the location manager service
        locmgr = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locmgr.requestLocationUpdates(locmgr.GPS_PROVIDER, 10, 10, gpsListener);

        mytext.setText("waiting for location");
    }

    //Start a location listener
    private class GPSListener implements LocationListener
    {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) 
        {
            //sets and displays the lat/long when a location is provided
            String latlong = "Lat: " + loc.getLatitude() + " Long: " + loc.getLongitude();   
            mytext.setText(latlong);
        }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) 
    {

    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) 
    {

    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
    Bundle extras) 
    {

    }
}
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the minimum distance when you call requestLocationUpdates method.

```
locmgr.requestLocationUpdates(locmgr.GPS_PROVIDER, 10, 2, gpsListener);
```

[Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.location.LocationListener%29) is the explenation.

Comment: I tried this already, but there is the same problem (maybe because i'm using an emulator)

Comment: Yes maybe. I don't have any other opinion.

Comment: Do you think that if I try the application on a real phone, it can work? The problem is that my phone is broken and I'm using an old phone now.

Comment: I think yes. Once it gets the gps location, it gets the new location even if it is not so far from the previous one. At least I didn't have any problem about it while trying my apps with real device.

Comment: Thank you. Then i'll try as soon as possible i can use a phone with the gps feature.

Comment: And another thing. Why, with some AVD, gps works fine, but with some other AVD (like 4" WGA or 5.4" FWVGA), after 2 or 3 points, it stops to receive other points?

Comment: I haven't used AVD for a long time. So I don't have much experience about AVD s. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is correct behaviour due to GPS precision. In other words 20-30m from current point is the same position from GPS's point of view

Comment: I thouth that too. Isn't there a way to change the precision on the emulator?